# Combining two rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The following is the result of a query on a single table:

`ID  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
1   -1      300     400
2   200     300     0`

What would the query look like if I want the result like the following:

`ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
200     300     400`

Basically, using `ColumnB` as reference and replace -1 and 0 with their respective non-zero counterparts under `ColumnA` and `ColumnC` (flattening?).

Some givens:

- Always two rows
- Always -1 for ColumnA, and 0 for ColumnC

This is something I have no experience with, so I'm asking SO's help. Thank you.

Comment: `select max(columna), max(columnb), max(columnc) from table` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all clm1,clm2,clm3 all are must be datatype int, rea, float then it apply

```
select Top(1) max(clm1), max(clm2), max(clm3) from tbl group by clm1,clm2,clm3
```

other try this,

```
select max(clm1), max(clm2), max(clm3) from tbl
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from 
( select ID ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, 
       , lead (ColumnA, 1, 'default') over (order over ID) as ColumnAlead 
    from table 
) tt 
where tt.ColumnC <> 0
```